# Create dynamic profile image in UWP app

Tags: drawing, uwp

I want to display profile images for users in my app. If no image is available from data source I want to generate those dynamic images Microsoft uses (containing the initials of a persons name).

Is this possible in UWP? I have found samples resulting in types from `Windows.Graphics.Imaging` namespace but they are manipulating existing images and not creating new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RenderTargetBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) has option to render your UI Elements to Images which can almost match the Image Format  that you are looking for with little fiddling. Below is the method that will render the Image from a Grid.

```cs
public static async Task<IRandomAccessStream> RenderToRandomAccessStream(this UIElement element)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await rtb.RenderAsync(element);

    var pixelBuffer = await rtb.GetPixelsAsync();
    var pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();

    // Useful for rendering in the correct DPI
    var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();

    var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                         BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
                         (uint)rtb.PixelWidth,
                         (uint)rtb.PixelHeight,
                         displayInformation.RawDpiX,
                         displayInformation.RawDpiY,
                         pixels);

    await encoder.FlushAsync();
    stream.Seek(0);

    return stream;
}
```

Taken from [Render XAML to image, Blur app UI, or how to enable awesome user experiences in your UWP app](http://metulev.com/render-xaml-to-image-and-more/)

But there is a catch here. `RenderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(UIElement Reference)` will only render an element that is attached to VisualTree. i.e, it can only convert a UIElement to Grid if it is present on the View. (Trust Me, Setting Visibility to Collapsed will not work).

So what I ended up doing is setting the Grid Width/Height to 50 But Image Width/Height to 60.

**See My XAML**

```xml
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Visibility="Visible" Name="GRDData" Background="LightBlue">
        <TextBlock Name="tbModded" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
    <Image Width="60" Height="60" x:Name="bgImage" Margin="10,0"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0">
        <Run x:Name="FN" />
        <Run x:Name="LN" />
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Now this is my code behind. Just for the sake of showing that Element is in the backend, I am setting the Grid Background to Red rather than Blue like the way it is in `xaml`.

```cs
private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string FirstName = "Test data";
    FN.Text = FirstName;
    string LastName = "Data Item";
    LN.Text = LastName;
    string ModdedString = FirstName.Substring(0, 1) + LastName.Substring(0, 1);
    tbModded.Text = ModdedString;
    GRDData.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    IRandomAccessStream stream = await RenderToRandomAccessStream(GRDData);
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.SetSource(stream);
    bgImage.Source = image;
}
```

End **Output** Will be

[image]

Comment: A good solution for getting rid of the control is to place it in the background of another one. So it's still in the visual tree but is not visible at it's position.

Comment: An even better solution would be to not abuse a type meant for use with the visual tree only, and pick the correct type instead. The [BitmapImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) class looks like a viable solution.

Comment: @IInspectable I am already using BitmapImage in the Render to Load it to   Image control. Are you saying in xaml also it should be BitMapImage instead of Image Control?

Comment: Your `RenderToRandomAccessStream` implementation is specifically meant to render UI content. You could implement the same functionality, without using an element from the visual tree. This looks a lot like you are reusing an implementation, without knowing, what it does, or when it shouldn't be used in favor of another solution.